# Using write_volatile and read_volatile for larger blocks of memory

Tags: rust

I am trying to work with volatile memory. What is the most efficient way to copy large byte array or string in this way? I am looking for something with several performance as `memcpy`. I would assume that simply iterating in a large loop and writing byte-by-byte using `write_volatile` isn't the most efficient option.

Comment: Maybe you can write in chunks of `usize`, e.g. https://rust.godbolt.org/z/PsTPsd1cG?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman is it as efficient as memcpy? I thought that x86 has actually instructions for blockcopy of memory that would be much more efficient than doing it manually and I am assuming standard memcpy implementation uses those.

Comment: I guess I am looking for volatile equivalent of https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html

Comment: [It only exists as an unstable intrinsic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/intrinsics/fn.volatile_copy_nonoverlapping_memory.html). It lowers to LLVM's volatile memcpy. But [the behavior is not specified](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#id500), and this is probably why LLVM is not allowed to optimize the loop to volatile memcpy.

Comment: And about the rep instructions, they're only so efficient on some platforms. Usually memcpy is implemented as best for the platform.